# Getting Exception saying settings can't be found

Tags: php, json

I get an Exception saying that settings can't be found. I need help please, I don't know how to repair that and I need it quickly.

That are my files I don't put the folders but there are in the correct folder so i don't know why i get that error, thanks if you can help me fixing this.. you can see the github of that project here : https://github.com/dialtoneuk/Syscrack2017;
You can't mount it in your host because it isn't finished.

ERROR:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Framework\Exceptions\ApplicationException: Setting does not exist in /var/www/html/src/Application/Settings.php:181
>   Stack trace:
>
> #0 /var/www/html/src/Syscrack/BetaKeys.php(119): Framework\Application\Settings::getSetting('syscrack_betake...')
>
> #1 /var/www/html/src/Syscrack/BetaKeys.php(31): Framework\Syscrack\BetaKeys->getBetakeys()
>
> #2 /var/www/html/cronjob/cronjob.betakeys.php(10): Framework\Syscrack\BetaKeys->__construct()
>
> #3 {main}
>     thrown in /var/www/html/src/Application/Settings.php on line 181

settings.json file

```
    {
    "filesystem_root": "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}",
    "filesystem_separator": "\/",
    "filesystem_default_extension": ".json",
    "filesystem_default_access": "0777",
    "developer_page": "developer",
    "developer_disabled": false,
    "database_connection_file": "conf\/database\/connection.json",
    "database_schema_file":"conf\/database\/databaseschema.json",
    "user_default_group": "guest",
    "user_group_admin": "admin",
    "user_group_developer": "developer",
    "user_allow_registrations": true,
    "user_require_betakey": true,
    "error_log_location": "conf\/errorlog.json",
    "error_display_page": true,
    "error_logging": true,
    "active_log_location": "conf\/activelog.json",
    "active_log_enabled": false,
    "active_log_showdeveloper": false,
    "api_use_get": true,
    "api_default_method": "endpoint",
    "api_method_length": 32,
    "logger_max_errors": "32",
    "controller_url_length": 4048,
    "controller_namespace": "Framework\\Views\\Pages\\",
    "controller_index_root": "\/",
    "controller_index_page": "index",
    "controller_page_folder": "src\/Views\/Pages\/",
    "database_driver": "mysql",
    "database_charset": "utf8",
    "database_collation": "utf8_unicode_ci",
    "database_prefix": "",
    "session_timeout": "{60 * 60 * 2}",
    "session_update_lastaction": true,
    "middlewares_enabled": true,
    "middlewares_location": "src\/Views\/Middleware\/",
    "middlewares_namespace": "Framework\\Views\\Middleware\\",
    "registration_password_length": 8,
    "facebook_enabled": true,
    "facebook_app_id": "",
    "facebook_app_secret": "",
    "facebook_app_version": "v2.8",
    "facebook_redirect_url": "http:\/\/{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI]'}",
    "online_timeframe": "{60 * 60 * 2}",
    "syscrack_game_name": "beta",
    "syscrack_bank_type": "bank",
    "syscrack_bitcoin_type": "bitcoin",
    "syscrack_market_type": "market",
    "syscrack_virus_type": "virus",
    "syscrack_npc_type": "npc",
    "syscrack_vpc_type": "vpc",
    "syscrack_cracker_type": "cracker",
    "syscrack_hasher_type": "hasher",
    "syscrack_firewall_type": "firewall",
    "syscrack_text_type": "text",
    "syscrack_cpu_type": "cpu",
    "syscrack_download_type": "download",
    "syscrack_collector_type": "collector",
    "syscrack_software_namespace": "Framework\\Syscrack\\Game\\Softwares\\",
    "syscrack_software_location": "src\/Syscrack\/Game\/Softwares\/",
    "syscrack_addressdatabase_location": "syscrack\/addressdatabase\/",
    "syscrack_bankdatabase_location": "syscrack\/bankdatabase\/",
    "syscrack_filedatabase_extension": ".json",
    "syscrack_bank_default_balance": 1000,
    "syscrack_bitcoin_live": true,
    "syscrack_bitcoin_sellprice": 500,
    "syscrack_bitcoin_buyprice": 550,
    "syscrack_bitcoin_url": "https:\/\/blockchain.info\/ticker",
    "syscrack_bitcoin_country": "USD",
    "syscrack_default_bank": 1,
    "syscrack_bank_accountnumber_length": 8,
    "syscrack_currency": "\u00a3",
    "syscrack_master_user": 1,
    "syscrack_npc_filepath": "syscrack\/npc\/",
    "syscrack_npc_page_location": "syscrack\/npc\/",
    "syscrack_log_current": "current",
    "syscrack_log_location": "syscrack\/logs\/",
    "syscrack_startup_on_verification": true,
    "syscrack_lowest_iprange": 192,
    "syscrack_whois_computer": 1,
    "syscrack_level_expert": 100,
    "syscrack_level_advanced": 50,
    "syscrack_level_normal": 50,
    "syscrack_view_location": "syscrack\/",
    "syscrack_operations_location": "src\/Syscrack\/Game\/Operations\/",
    "syscrack_operations_namespace": "Framework\\Syscrack\\Game\\Operations\\",
    "syscrack_vminer_uniquename": "vminer",
    "syscrack_vddos_uniquename": "vddos",
    "syscrack_vspam_uniquename": "vspam",
    "syscrack_collector_static": false,
    "syscrack_collector_amount": 1000,
    "syscrack_collector_btc_amount": 0.5,
    "syscrack_marketstock_location": "syscrack\/stocks.json",
    "syscrack_default_processingtime": 10,
    "syscrack_internet_page": "internet",
    "syscrack_game_page": "game",
    "syscrack_hack_speed": 5.5,
    "syscrack_statistics_file": "syscrack\/statistics.json",
    "syscrack_statistics_enabled": true,
    "syscrack_software_allowedmethods": [
        "onInstalled",
        "onUninstalled",
        "onExecute",
        "onCollect"
    ],
    "syscrack_vpc_viewcount": 5,
    "syscrack_globe_enabled": true,
    "syscrack_betakey_location":"conf\/betakeys.json",
    "sycsrack_betakey_steps":3,
    "sycsrack_betakey_length":6
}
```

cronjob.betakeys.php file

```
<?php
require_once "../vendor/autoload.php";

use Framework\Syscrack\BetaKeys;


if( php_sapi_name() == 'cli' )
{

    $betakeys = new BetaKeys();

    $betakeys->generateBetaKeys( 1000 );

    //Echo out the betakeys

    print_r( $betakeys->getBetakeys() );
}

?>
```

BetaKeys.php file
`

```
/**
 * Lewis Lancaster 2017
 *
 * Class BetaKey
 *
 * @package Framework\Syscrack
 */

use Framework\Application\Settings;
use Framework\Application\Utilities\FileSystem;

class BetaKeys
{

    /**
     * @var null
     */

    private $keys = [];

    /**
     * BetaKey constructor.
     */

    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->keys = $this->getBetakeys();
    }

    /**
     * Adds the beta-key to the array and then saves
     *
     * @param $betakey
     */

    public function addBetaKey( $betakey )
    {

        $this->keys[] = $betakey;

        $this->saveBetaKeys();
    }

    /**
     * Removes a betakey from the list
     *
     * @param $betakey
     */

    public function removeBetaKey( $betakey )
    {

        foreach( $this->keys as $key=>$value )
        {

            if( $value == $betakey )
            {

                unset( $this->keys[ $key ] );
            }
        }

        $this->saveBetaKeys();
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if this beta-key exists
     *
     * @param $betakey
     *
     * @return bool
     */

    public function hasBetaKey( $betakey )
    {

        if( empty( $this->keys ) )
        {

            return false;
        }

        foreach( $this->keys as $key=>$value )
        {

            if( $value == $betakey )
            {

                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Saves the betakeys
     */

    public function saveBetaKeys()
    {

        FileSystem::writeJson( Settings::getSetting('syscrack_betakey_location'), $this->keys );
    }

    /**
     * Gets the beta keys
     *
     * @return null
     */

    public function getBetakeys()
    {

        if( FileSystem::fileExists( Settings::getSetting('syscrack_betakey_location') ) == false )
        {

            return null;
        }

        return FileSystem::readJson( Settings::getSetting('syscrack_betakey_location') );
    }

    /**
     * Generates a set of Betakeys
     *
     * @param int $count
     *
     * @return array
     */

    public function generateBetaKeys( $count=1 )
    {

        $keys = [];

        for( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ )
        {

            $keys[] = $this->getBetakey();
        }

        return $keys;
    }

    /**
     * Generates a new betakey
     *
     * @return string
     */

    private function getBetaKey()
    {

        $key = "";

        for( $i = 0; $i < Settings::getSetting('sycsrack_betakey_steps'); $i++ )
        {

            $step = "";

            for( $k = 0; $k < Settings::getSetting('sycsrack_betakey_length'); $k++ )
            {

                $step = $step . rand(0,9 );
            }

            $key = $key . "-" . $step;
        }

        return $key;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it the class Settings that can't be found, the file or the keys you're trying to get? Please add the actual exception to your question.

Comment: Error added to the post

Comment: The issue is in your Settings-class. When it loads the settings.json file, it uses `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to find the correct location. That value is set by the web server (since it is the web servers document root), so when you're calling the script through CLI, that value don't exist and the script won't find the correct path to the file.

Comment: So how can I fix this?

Comment: I've updated the answer below. You actually need to make sure that the settings get loaded, which you're currently not doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your Settings-class. When it tries to load the `settings.json` file, it uses `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to find the correct location.
That value is set by the web server (since it is the web servers document root), so when you're calling the script through CLI, that value don't exist and the script won't find the correct path to the file.

To solve it, simply add that key to the `$_SERVER` array in your `cronjob.betakeys.php`-file. Don't forget to load the settings, as well!

```
<?php
require_once "../vendor/autoload.php";

use Framework\Application\Settings;
use Framework\Syscrack\BetaKeys;

// Set the document root manually 
// (one level up since this file is in a sub directory).
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = realpath(__DIR__ . '/..');

// Now, make sure the settings get loaded!
Settings::preloadSettings();

if( php_sapi_name() == 'cli' )
{

    $betakeys = new BetaKeys();

    $betakeys->generateBetaKeys( 1000 );

    //Echo out the betakeys

    print_r( $betakeys->getBetakeys() );
}
```